# Comparing reliabilities of two systems of components

Tags: probability, statistics

A communication system consists of n components, each of which
will, independently, function with probability p. The total system
will be able to operate effectively if at least one half of its components
function. For what values of p is a 5 component system more likely
to operate than a 3 component system ?

Comment: I guess for no value of p should this be true.

Comment: If we have a system with odd number of components, will the system operate effectively if $(n-1)/2$ components function?

Comment: what is your definition of being effective??in what sense?

Comment: This is a nice problem based on binomial distributions to introduce ideas of system reliability.

Answer (score 0):

As a function of $p \in (0,1),$ find the probability a system of five is OK (three or more functioning components). Then find another such function of $p$ for the probability a system of three is OK. For what values of $p$ does the former function exceed the latter? This should not be too messy with binomial PDF and algebra. (It is not hard to see that the two functions are equal when $p = q = 1/2$.) But here is a computation in R that makes it easy to draw an illustrative plot.

```
 p = seq(0, 1, by=.001)
 five.ok = 1 - pbinom(2, 5, p)
 three.ok = 1 - pbinom(1, 3, p)
 plot(p, five.ok, type="l", col="blue", ylab="P(OK)", main="Sys5 (blue) and Sys3")
 lines(p, three.ok, col="orange", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 cross = min(p[five.ok > three.ok]); cross  # read [ ] as 'such as'
 ## 0.5
 abline(v = cross, col="green2")
```

[image]

It seems clear that the system of five (solid blue line) is more likely to be OK than the
system of three (dotted orange line) when $p > 1/2.$

Intuitively, if components are working more often than not,
it should be helpful to have more of them in the system.